# How do you scale your ActiveMQ vertically?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Can somebody share an experience concerning scaling vertically the ActiveMQ? I'm particularly interested how performance is affected by:

- NIO transport
- option org.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner
- disabling tightEncoding in OpenWire
- using various type of Message Stores (including KahaDB)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The items you mention above are all recommendations for scaling ActiveMQ as listed in the [How do I configure 10s of 1000s of Queues in a single broker?](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-10s-of-1000s-of-queues-in-a-single-broker-.html) page. I've utilized each of these tactics in various situations at customer sites and found that they help considerably.

- The NIO transport is good for using less sockets when there are a high number of connections into a broker vs. the TCP transport. This efficiency can improve the overall performance of the broker.
- I almost always recommend setting `org.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=false` simply because it helps considerably with performance.
- Disabling tight encoding is a subtle change and difficult to see the benefit. It depends on the types of messages that you're sending.
- The KahaDB outperforms any of the other stores for persistent messaging with ActiveMQ, especially on the trunk. There is a bug that is fixed only on the trunk currently that causes a dramatic increase in persistent messaging performance that will be part of 5.3.1 and 5.4.

I know that this info isn't concrete, but I hope it still helps.

Bruce

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for exactly that kind of information. Regards.